# Regex pattern for String not ending in a sequence

Tags: regex, xml, pattern-matching

I am trying to find all strings not ending with the sequence -6X.
What i'm trying to do is compare the value of an xml tag with a sequence.
If it matches then do some stuff.
However I am unable to do so. I want to achieve this without any lookaheads or lookbehinds.

I've tried using `.*[^-6X]`
However this does not work for strings ending in - or -5 .
I want to ignore strings ending in -6X only and every other pattern should work.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what language/tool do you use? Negative lookaheads may help you but they are not supported in all regex flavors

Comment: negative lookaheads are not supported I think. i am using this pattern in xml to compare the value of a tag with a string.

Comment: You don't need a regex, just test `string.endsWith(...)` or whatever your language has.

Comment: I am using xml.Sorry I didn't mention it in my question.I'll edit it.

Comment: Try `".*([^-].{2}|.[^6].|.{2}[^X])|.{0,2}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches Strings NOT ending with -6X:

```
.*?([^-]..|.[^6].|..[^X])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/omwkQ3/2